# Delete a blitzball technique?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

Is there anyway to delete and/or forget a technique that someone learns? From what I can tell you can only learn so many techniques.. how do you delete them?

Comment: I'm not sure so commenting not answering but I think the limited number of techniques is predefined, not a numerical limit. That is a character will have all their possible techniques defined. I thought there was some indication of what techniques they could learn by virtue of a "-----" rather than a blank in the skills list which makes this more obvious. Pretty sure you can't delete them though anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the information available to you. You can't unlearn techs and you wouldn't want to.

Each player can learn all techs. Here's how that works:

- Each player starts with a number of techs that they can learn.
- One of those techs is the first key tech that will unlock the ability to
  learn the next group of techs.
- The next group which includes the second key tech for unlocking
  the following group after that.
- This group includes the third and final key tech for unlocking the ability to learn all remaining techs.
- The key techs and distribution of techs are different for each player.
- Learn techs by using techcopy (Low-level players cannot learn techs from high-level players) or as tournament rewards (you can't learn abilities from tiers you haven't unlocked for that character).

Here's an example (I've noted the key techs in bold - once you learn those, you gain access to the next level):

> ### Wakka
>
> - ***Starting Techs***: Venom Shot
> - ***Normal Techs***: Anti-Drain, Brawler, Elite Defence, Hi-Risk, Nap Pass, Nap Shot, Nap Tackle, Sphere Shot, Spin Ball, Venom Pass, Venom Shot, Venom Shot 2, Venom Tackle,  Volley Shot, Wither Pass, **Wither Shot**
> - ***Level 1 Techs***: Anti-Venom, **Drain Tackle**, Drain Tackle 2, Golden Arm, Grip Gloves, Nap Pass 2, Nap Shot 2, Pile Wither, Regen, Venom Pass 2, Venom Pass 3, Volley Shot 2, Wither Pass 2, Wither Pass 3, Wither Shot 2, Wither Tackle, Wither Tackle 2
> - ***Level 2 Techs***: Anti-Drain 2, Anti-Nap, Anti-Wither, Auroch's Spirit, Drain Tackle 3, Good Morning!, Invisible Shot, Nap Tackle 2, Pile Venom, Super Goalie, **Tackle Slip**, Tackle Slip 2, Venom Shot 3, Venom Tackle 3, Volley Shot 3
> - ***Level 3 Techs***: Anti-Nap 2, Anti-Venom 2, Anti-Wither 2, Gamble, Nap Pass 3, Nap Shot 3, Nap Tackle 3, Venom Tackle 2, Wither Shot 3, Wither Tackle 3

Each player can only equip a number of techs according to their level. Once you reach level 3, you can equip one tech and, as you level, you will be able to equip more up to the maximum of 5.

All of this information is available in the many guides on the subject, but I find [AlaskaFox's Blitzball Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/19103) the most useful as it has complete player listings with each player's key techs and which techs are in which tier.

Comment: Woah. I never knew this. I just figured certain characters could only learn certain techs as a way to show what position they belong in.

Comment: There was a ton of stuff you just said I did not know. Thanks for taking the time to write that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard cap to the number of techniques each player can learn. Each player has a list of techniques they can learn but there is no situation where learning a technique could prevent a player from learning a different technique.

Consequently, there is no situation where deleting a known move could be useful or necessary so there is no way to do so.